# Design pattern for object assuming new features at runtime?

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns

Suppose I have a class `House`.

I want to be adding specifications to my house, like a `Garage`, a `SwimmingPool` or a `Garden`, each coming with its own set of new methods.

If I used inheritance, I would have subclasses `HouseWithGarage`, `HouseWithSwimmingPool` and `HouseWithGarden`. But what if I wanted to have an object with a garage and a garden at the same time? What if later I wanted to add a swimmingpool to that same object at runtime?

Obviously inheritance doesn't work well here. Are you aware of any design pattern appropriate for this kind of problem?

Comment: I guess you want to take a look to the Decorator pattern, or see if you can resolve what you want using multiple interfaces, each one defining the methods for Garage, SwimingPool, and Garden.

Comment: @Juan Problem with the decorator pattern is that it doesn't allow you to retrieve the object that added the feature, it is nested deep into the wrapper. I want to be able to tell my House object to give me its Garage object anytime. Multiple interfaces is ok at compile time but as mentioned I would like to add features at run-time.

Comment: "Each with its own set of new methods" - how do you expect this to work? Types are resolved statically, at each point in your program you know the exact set of methods that can be called on your object. Do you want some kind of dynamic behaviour, where you can call `ParkCar()` on your `House` and crash at runtime if it didn't have a `Garage` attached?

Comment: @V0ldek My client would make sure that my House has a Garage before working with it.I was thinking for example about having a dictionnary inside my House class. The key "Garage" would return me the appropriate object.

Comment: If you truly need dynamic runtime properties it's woth looking into what's called abstract document pattern. Detailed explanation is available here https://martinfowler.com/apsupp/properties.pdf and an example implementation here https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/abstract-document/

Answer (score 2):

The pattern that closest describes what you are looking for is the Composite Pattern, described in "Design Patterns" by Gamma et al.

[image]

From the Gamma book:

**Component**

1. Declares the interface for object in the composition.
2. Implements default behavior for the interface common to all classes, as appropriate.
3. Declares an interface for accessing and managing its child components.
4. Optionally defines an interface for accessing a component's parent in the recursive structure and implements it if that's appropriate.

**Leaf**

1. Represents leaf objects in the composition. A leaf has no children.
2. Defines behavior for primitive objects in the composition.

**Composite**

1. Defines behavior for components having children.
2. Stores child components.
3. Implements child-related operations in the Component interface.

A `House` will be a `Component`. `Garage`, `Garden` and `SwimmingPool` will be either a `Leaf` or a `Composite` depending on whether they are composed of child components or not.

Needless to say (?), these interfaces can *many* operations besides `operation()`.

Answer (score 1):

Better with "has-a" than "is-a", which supports your statement regarding inheritance.

```
public interface IFeature { ... }

public class Garage : IFeature
{
   public Garage(string colour){ ... }
}

public class House 
{
  private readonly IList<IFeature> _features = new List<IFeature>();

  public House() { ... }

  public House(IList<IFeature> features) { _features = features; }

  public IFeature AddFeature(IFeature feature)
  {
     _features.Add(feature);
     return feature;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you want to hold a collection of components at runtime and force your clients to make sure that a given component is added before working with it. I'm not aware of a design pattern for that, but you can simply hold a dictionary of attached components and look them up by type:

```
public class House
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _components = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void AddComponent<T>([DisallowNull] T component) where T : class, IHouseComponent
    {
        _components.Add(typeof(T), component);
    }

    [return: MaybeNull]
    public T GetComponent<T>() where T : class, IHouseComponent
    {
        return _components.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var component) ? (T) component : null;
    }
}
```

So when you have a `house` and a `garage` you can do:

```
House house;
Garage garage;

...

house.AddComponent(garage);

...

// somewhere else
var garage = house.GetComponent<Garage>();
```

`IHouseComponent` is a marker interface so that you have to explicitly implement it before adding it to a `House` (so you can't just add any `object`).

If it's possible for multiple components of the same type to be added, just hold a list of them in the dictionary:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _components = ...

public void AddComponent<T>(...)
{
    if (_components.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var list)
    {
        list.Add(component);
    }
    else
    {
        _components.Add(typeof(T), new List<object>{ component });
    }
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetComponents<T>() ...
{
    if (_components.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var list))
    {
        return list.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```